# How to add dict entry after assigning variable in yaml?

Tags: ansible, yaml

I want to create a dict **myVar2** that contains **myVar1** and additional entry, something like this:

```
myVar1:
  entry1: "text1"
  entry2: "text2"
myVar2: "{{ myVar1 }}"
  additional: "entry"
```

and when I try to launch **ansible** with this vars file then I get an error:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `combine` filter:

```
myVar1:
  entry1: "text1"
  entry2: "text2"
myVarTmp:
  additional: "entry"
myVar2: "{{ myVar1 | combine(myVarTmp) }}"
```